# Change Maven Home Path

Tags: java, macos, maven

I have recently started working on MacOS, I installed Maven and when i checked out for it's Maven Home Path,I found out a strange path and I need to change this path.
When I run mvn -v command in terminal,i am get this output

```
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 15.0.1, vendor: N/A, runtime: 
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Kindly help me changing the Maven path to a different version that I desire.

Comment: The first thing is: Why do you need to change the path where Maven is installed? If you can call it from command line it's fine? What is the real problem here? Why do you need to change it? Apart from that if you use brew.sh this is the way it works...

Answer (score -1):

binary home, using set o export and the path to maven root directory...
repository,